# Django template dynamically add rows and colums does not work

Tags: python, django

I'm displaying blog list looping through the list in django and the blogs are displayed 3 columns in a row and the rows and columns are dynamically added but it doesn't work yet.

```
<div class="container">
    {% for post in post_list %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
         <div class="row py-5">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 pb-5">
        <div class="card blog-card my-5">
            {% if post.image %}
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Blog Post Image">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="blog-card-text">
                <div>
                    <img src="{% static 'blog/images/logo.png' %}" alt="MMDT logo" class="blog-created-img">
                    <small>{{ post.created_on }}</small>
                </div>
                <div class="card-title mb-0">
                    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">{{ post.title}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-text">
                    <small>{{ post.author }} | {{ post.view_count }}</small>
                </div>
                <div class="card-text">
                    {{ post.content|slice:":120" | striptags }} <span>...</span>
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="mt-0 mb-3">
                        Read More
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 or forloop.last %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Any idea to fix this and thanks in advance.